# Document Db async method ExecuteNextAsync() stuck in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, async-await, deadlock

I have a Cloud service ASP.NET application which is consuming document db API (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.0). Here I need to call asynchronous code from synchronous code. My call to execute results on document db is

If I call it from synchronous method:

```
var result = Task.Run (() => schemaResults.ExecuteNextAsync ()).Result;
```

If I call it from asynchronous method:

```
var result = await schemaResults.ExecuteNextAsync ();
```

OR

```
var result = await schemaResults.ExecuteNextAsync ().ConfigureAwait (false);
```

**The code works perfectly fine if I run it on localhost on Azure emulator but when I deploy it on Azure, it gets stuck** at the above call. Seems like it has gone into a deadlock.

Any help?

Comment: `Here I need to call asynchronous code from synchronous code.` Why?

Comment: Because I have synchronous wrappers over Document db Async library

Comment: [You shouldn't do that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/).

Comment: Then how should I call async methods from synchronous piece of code?

Comment: You don't. You call the asynchronous methods and use `await`. [Otherwise, it's not asynchronous](https://vimeo.com/ondemand/asynctime/225439490?autoplay=1).

Comment: Cannot use await operator in non-async method.
void Foo()
{
     BarAsync().Wait();
}

Comment: You make the calling method asynchronous.

Comment: Cant make it asynchronous. It is enforced in architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried updating Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.0 to Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.14.1
It contains fixes for the deadlocks that occurs in ASP.NET context

Release Notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sdk-dotnet#release-notes